# Why does aligning two elements in a column in bootstrap behave differently based on the element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering why does this code place the h1 and p elements below each other:

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <h1>Header 1</h1>
          <p>Paragraph.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

And this code places the images below each other as well

```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <img src="img/sth.png" class="img-responsive"/>
          <img src="img/sth2.png" class="img-responsive"/>
       </div>
    </div>
```

But this code places the buttons next to each other

```
<div class="row">    
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <button><a href="http://www.apple.com" target="_blank"><img class="img- responsive" src="img/app.png" /></a></button>
    <button><a href="http://www.googleplay.com" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/google.png" /></a></button>                  
 </div>
```

Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h1` a `img` tags have by default the css property [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) set as `display: block` so they don't have other elements side by side

Answer (score 0):

h1 ,p , img are a block type but button isn't.